# Find tetrahedron vertex given 3 vertices of a face and the 3 opposite angles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra

I have the following tetrahedron:

[image]

which I know the coordinates of $P$, $Q$ and $R$ and the value of angles $\theta_0$, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

I need to find the coordinates of vertex $E$. Is that possible? If so, how can I find $E$?

So far, I have tried the following approaches:

1. Solving a system by using angles between vectors $\vec{ER}$, $\vec{EP}$ and $\vec{EQ}$:

$$\cos{\theta_0}=\frac{\vec{ER} \cdot \vec{EP}}{||\vec{ER}\||||\vec{EP}||}$$
$$\cos{\theta_1}=\frac{\vec{ER} \cdot \vec{EQ}}{||\vec{ER}\||||\vec{EQ}||}$$
$$\cos{\theta_2}=\frac{\vec{EP} \cdot \vec{EQ}}{||\vec{EP}\||||\vec{EQ}||}$$

By doing this I ended up with a system which I can't solve.

2. Solving system by using [Law of Cosines](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html) between unknown edges $||\vec{ER}||$, $||\vec{EP}||$, $||\vec{EQ}||$ and known ones $||\vec{PQ}||$, $||\vec{QR}||$, $||\vec{RQ}||$:

$$||\vec{PQ}||^2=||\vec{EP}||^2 + ||\vec{EQ}||^2 - 2||\vec{EP}||||\vec{EQ}||\cos{\theta_0}$$
$$||\vec{QR}||^2=||\vec{EQ}||^2 + ||\vec{ER}||^2 - 2||\vec{EQ}||||\vec{ER}||\cos{\theta_1}$$
$$||\vec{RP}||^2=||\vec{ER}||^2 + ||\vec{EP}||^2 - 2||\vec{ER}||||\vec{EP}||\cos{\theta_2}$$

By doing this I ended up with a similar system as the previous one.

3. I also tried to use [Sine Rule](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Law_of_Sines#:%7E:text=The%20Law%20of%20Sines%20is,the%20circumradius%2C%20another%20useful%20function.) finding the circumradius for each face:

$$circumradius_{EPQ} = \frac{||\vec{PQ}||}{2sin(\theta_0)}$$
$$circumradius_{EQR} = \frac{||\vec{QR}||}{2sin(\theta_1)}$$
$$circumradius_{ERP} = \frac{||\vec{RP}||}{2sin(\theta_2)}$$

but it also actually didn't lead me to find a solution.

I'm not sure if there is a single solution for these settings or even if it is possible to find one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This nice question seems to be more suitable for Math StackExchange.com.

Comment: Hi @MikhailBorovoi thanks for the feedback, indeed I'm confused about the two sites. Could you clarify the difference briefly?

Comment: Humm ok I just found it https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange

Comment: Well you can suppose that your points have coordinates $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(p,q,0),(r,s,t)$ where $p$ and $q$ are given.  Your conditions then give three polynomial equations of fourth degree  in the unknowns $r,s,t$.  Not sure if this is of any use for your purposes.

Comment: Hi @user131781 thanks for the hint. This fourth degree 3-unknow system was what a have found. Honestly speaking I don't know if I have the required skill to solve it or if it doesn't have a solution. I m running it on Mathematica. 40 minutes and no response yet.

Comment: Not all polynomial equations (even in one unknown) have solutions in elementary functions of coefficients. However, for given *numbers* $p,q$ you can solve your system numerically.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi I'm still on going but it seems that this problem has not a canonical solution. Wu-Ritt’s zero decomposition algorithm is my next station on this travel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu%27s_method_of_characteristic_set